# Should I check whether a window exists before using WinClose?

Tags: autohotkey

The documentation for **[WinClose](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm)** includes a code sample which checks **[IfWinExist](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm)** before attempting to close it.

```
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad  ; check if window exists
    WinClose                    ; close window found above
```

I've also seen scripts use WinClose on its own without checking whether the window exists.

```
WinClose, Untitled - Notepad    ; close window without checking if it exists
```

I haven't been able to find any reason to use one method over the other. My script seems to work fine either way either way, making the choice seem like personal preference.

**Is there any reason to check if a window exists before closing it with with WinClose?**

Comment: Afaik, ifwinexist only checks if the window is running, I don't think it puts the focus on that window. So if your focus is on window A and you check for window B and then issue a close command, I think you will close window A and not window B...

Comment: @RobertIlbrink It will close the `Last Found` window i.e. window B in your example as explained by @Dennies_E in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to check if a window exists before closing it. If no matching window exists, `WinClose` will simply not do anything. That's not what the example is trying to say.

The example tries to say that you don't need to repeat the WinTitle and/or WinText of the target window when using `WinClose`. It just saves you some typing (and performance) in some cases.
For example:

```
IfWinExist, Untitled - Notepad
    ;do stuff
    ;do more stuff
    ;etc
    WinClose ;close the window found above
```

This is explained in the documentation of `WinTitle`, paragraph **The "Last Found" Window**:

> This is the window most recently found by IfWin[Not]Exist, WinExist(), IfWin[Not]Active, WinActive(), WinWait[Not]Active, or WinWait. **It can make scripts easier to create and maintain** since the WinTitle and WinText of the target window do not need to be repeated for every windowing command. **In addition, scripts perform better** because they don't need to search for the target window again after it has been found the first time.

Comment: Will the script perform better if the IfWinExist is excluded? (Since there's also only one lookup)

Comment: There would probably not be a measurable difference. There's only one lookup, but you're still executing two commands instead of one. I'd go with whatever reads best.